# which in those queries is better in performance and why?

Tags: linq

The first Linq query is

```
(
    from r in db.Rider
    join s in db.Spaces
        on r.SpaceID equals s.SpaceID
    group new { r,s } by new { r.SpaceID, s.SpaceCode }
    into grp
    select new
    {
        Count=grp.Count(),
        grp.Key.SpaceID,
        grp.Key.SpaceCode
    }
)
```

The second Linq query is:

```
(
    from r in db.Rider
    join s in db.Spaces
        on r.SpaceID equals s.SpaceID
     select new {r,s}).GroupBy(r => r.SpaceID)
  .Select(data => new Result                               
       {
           SpaceID = data.FirstOrDefault().r.SpaceID,
           SpaceCode = data.FirstOrDefault().s.SpaceCode
       });
```

Which of those queries is better in terms of performance and why?

Comment: Only you can tell. Also, the queries are different so how useful is the comparison?

Comment: how different it the same result ? which different way of grouping and select different entity

Comment: One query has Count, the other hasn't. Also, you don't specify which ORM your're using. Even if you do, usually it's impossible to tell what will perform better. You'll have to do your own benchmarking and *maybe* return with a question as to *why* a specific query performs poorly, accompanied by ample information of database provider, translated SQL query, indexes etc.

Comment: You can use   **LiqPad** to convert your LINQ statement to TSql and then use the SQL Server **EstimatedPlan**  to get the right result of comparing the two queries  [https://www.linqpad.net/]

Comment: Your second query is wrong and is not equivalent to the first! I think In the group by clause "SpaceCode" is dropped and also does not contain any Count aggregate function. Obviously, these two queries are not equal. In terms of performance evaluation, you can utilize profiling tools such as SQL profiler to find the result query and find the difference in performance.

Answer (score 0):

Your First LINQ query equivalent SQL query is :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS [Count], [t0].[SpaceID], [t1].[SpaceCode]
FROM [Rider] AS [t0]
INNER JOIN [Spaces] AS [t1] ON [t0].[SpaceID] = ([t1].[SpaceID])
GROUP BY [t0].[SpaceID], [t1].[SpaceCode]
```

But I got an error in your second LINQ Query. are you sure it is correct?